# return statement

Tags: javascript

*I think I have missunderstod the syntax, I need a [generic energy drink]. It returns the same value.*

```
var tal1 = antalAr(1000000,1000);
document.writeln("A loan of 1000000 SEK is paid after " + 
Math.ceil(answer) + " years if the installment is 1000kr/mån.");


var tal2 = antalAr(1500000,500);
document.writeln("A loan of 1500000 SEK is paid after " + 
Math.ceil(answer) + " years if the installment is 500kr/mån.");

        function antalAr(lan, amortering)
        {
            amoyear = amortering * 12;
            for( var answer = 1; amoyear * answer <= loan; answer++){}
            return answer;
        }
```

Comment: loan is undefined in antalAr(lan, amortering){ }

Comment: Amongst other issues, you're not actually using the return value (tal1 and tal2 respectively). (It should presumably be used in place of "answer" in your Math.ceils.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

answer is only declared in the local function scope in antalAr(). You can't use it outside the function.

try this:

```
var tal1 = antalAr(1000000,1000);
document.writeln("A loan of 1000000 SEK is paid after " + 
Math.ceil(tal1) + " years if the installment is 1000kr/mån.");


var tal2 = antalAr(1500000,500);
document.writeln("A loan of 1500000 SEK is paid after " + 
Math.ceil(tal2) + " years if the installment is 500kr/mån.");

        function antalAr(loan, amortering)
        {
            amoyear = amortering * 12;
            for( var answer = 1; amoyear * answer <= loan; answer++){}
            return answer;
        }
```

edit: oh, a typo as well

Comment: Thanks man, I understand now that the return value in going to be saved in tal1 and tal2. great! Man I love this place!

Comment: pfft!  I didn't even notice this problem at a glance.  +1.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a simple typo:

```
function antalAr(lan, amortering)
```

should be

```
function antalAr(loan, amortering)
```

Also, `answer` should be declared outside the for-loop:

```
function antalAr(loan, amortering) {
    var answer, amoyear = amortering * 12;
    for(answer = 1; amoyear * answer <= loan; answer++){}
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: I still get the same result, why is that?